# Inclusion of external javascript libraries in Adobe Edge Animate projects

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-edge

How is it possible to add an external javascript library to an adobe edge animate project and use it for example in a click event of a button?

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the latest version (3.0) that came out yesterday. It includes support for external JS libraries.

Comment: If one has the free 1.5.0 version (early release) and he's not willing to pay, my answer is the way to go. Can't undestand the -1, since anyway it works.

Comment: Agreed - will +1 your answer since it is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
Just edit the index.html file to include your js library, then you can call it from wherever you want.